# Autosearch table on default value

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Light Javascript Table Filter to auto/fast search the table.
I want it to search with the default value first. However it only searches when I type something.

Please take a look [`http://codepen.io/shank09/pen/wWBVGE`](http://codepen.io/shank09/pen/wWBVGE)

I defaulted value "Doe", in order for it to search I have to type something

Can i trigger keyboard action upon auto focusing the input field.

Tried this but no luck.

```
function autosearch() {
    document.getElementById("quicksearch").value = '03/-';
    onPressBackspace();

}

function onPressBackspace() {
    document.getElementById("quicksearch").focus();
    document.getElementById("quicksearch").value = document.getElementById("quicksearch").value.substring(0, document.getElementById("quicksearch").value.length - 1);
}
```

.

**UPDATE**

```
function autosearch() {
   document.getElementById("quicksearch").value = '987';
   var s = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter')[0];
   triggerEvent(s, "input");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtering happens when "input" event triggers. But when you have a default value the event is not firing. You need to trigger it by yourself.
It's easier with jQuery but you can do it with vanilla JavaScript as well.

## jQuery

Just [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the event after the `LightTableFilter.init();`

Like that: `$("light-table-filter").trigger("input");`

## JavaScript

Create this function a line before `document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {...`

```
function triggerEvent(el, type){
 if ('createEvent' in document) {
    // modern browsers, IE9+
    var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    e.initEvent(type, false, true);
    el.dispatchEvent(e);
 } else {
    // IE 8
    var e = document.createEventObject();
    e.eventType = type;
    el.fireEvent('on'+e.eventType, e);
 }
}
```

And then call this function after the init - `LightTableFilter.init();`

Like this:

```
var s = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter')[0];
triggerEvent(s, "input");
```

Comment: thanks that worked, how can i achieve the same thing when a click on a button which inserts into the input field. See updated code in link

Comment: Same way, trigger yourself the input event after you change the value

Comment: Please see the update in the question, is that how to do it? it didnt work

Comment: How can i tigger the input for the button click?

Comment: This code is fine but I can see in the codepen update that it is out of the scope of the function `triggerEvent` so you need to put it before the `})(document);`

Comment: hey, thanks. Im unclear. i updated codepen, is that what you mean? it didnt work

Comment: No. you need to take the whole function inside. The exact code you have in the UPDATE

Comment: i did that, the onclick is no longer working. Updated codepen

Comment: Make sense... it's because of scope. you have several options but I guess you are a newbie so I don't want to confuse you. It's not the best practice but it will work. Take the function back outside and also copy the whole `triggerEvent` outside as well. Don't delete the one inside, make a copy